# Use Google App Script to write a phone number to a doc that allows user to select the whole number with single press

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm using App Script to create a residents directory (a Google Doc) for our neighborhood. Phone numbers look good but when the user presses on the phone number to select it, only a portion delimited by "-" selects (then the user must drag to select the whole number). We would like the entire phone number to be selectable as a single unit so it is easy for our resident to select, then call.

```
var thePhoneNumber = "111-222-3333";
theTableCell.appendParagraph(thePhoneNumber);
```

In the example above, a user presses on "222" and only gets "222", not "111-222-3333". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  could try setting a [tel link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

```
const thePhoneNumber = "111-222-3333";
theTableCell
    .setText(thePhoneNumber)
    .setLinkUrl(`tel:${thePhoneNumber.replace(/-/g,"")}`);
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks.